# Can I convert a 2.5W DC to AC with a 120W DC-AC Inverter?

Tags: low-power, inverter, dc-ac

I want to convert the output of USB to AC voltage, and I come across with this 120W 12V power inverter. Is it possible to step up the 5V DC to 12V, later convert it to AC with a 120W DC-AC inverter? If so, what will I get? As I know 120W is the max. output power, do I need to concern about the input?

P.S. I'm a self-learner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theoretical maximum you could get out with 2.5W in (5V @ 500mA) would be 2.5W out.

A 120W inverter will likely have very bad efficiency at such low power out, and you are going through two conversions (the inefficiencies multiply), so I would guess you'd be lucky to get 1W out, and it's completely possible, maybe likely, that it would not fire up the 120W inverter at all.

In most cases there should be a better way of accomplishing whatever it is that you are trying to do.

Comment: I see. Do you have any better suggestion?

Comment: What are  you planning on using the 120VAC (or 240VAC) for?

Comment: The end project is a battery-less mouse. As mentioned before, I'm using the output of USB. In order to perform **wireless power transmission**, AC voltage is required as an input. Someone suggested me to convert the DC voltage to AC, later step it down to desired value. It kinda make sense to me. I do notice that the output frequency of the power inverter is low. I believe I need at least 100khz. Any idea?

Comment: The Qi standard would be a place to start- it is designed for wireless power applications < 5W. Chipsets are available from various companies such as TI.  Coupling is via a pair of pancake coils with some flat sheet ferrite core material.